# RODBC sqlFetch for tables in multiple databases on the server

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I'm trying to fetch/update a table in a sql database using R package RODBC.

OPTION 1 for SQL query works fine, but how to apply the same logic and refer to specific database (there are multiple) in OPTION 2 (not working) for fetch/update/save?

REF option brings the table from the default database (ie. equivalent to XXX, not XXX_Test)

```
channel <- odbcConnect(dsn="XXX")

# OPTION 1
# sql statements
Table_sql <- "select * from XXX_Test.dbo.Table"

# query the DB
Table <- sqlQuery(channel, query=Table_sql, as.is = TRUE)

#OPTION 2
Table2<-sqlFetch(channel,"XXX_Test.dbo.Table")

#Error in odbcTableExists(channel, sqtable) : 
#  ‘XXX_Test.dbo.Table’: table not found on channel

### REF
Table3<-sqlFetch(channel,"Table")
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your code seems legit, and it works for me (details: I'm using `DBI`+`odbc` to connect to SQL Server). I don't know that it'll be different, but since you're redacting the db name ... perhaps `"[XXX_Test].dbo.Table"`? If your DBMS doesn't use brackets, perhaps `'"XXX_Test".dbo.Table'` (the use of double-quotes in most/all DBMSes delineates identifiers like table/column names, not to be confused with single quotes which delineate string literals). Note my use of single-quotes around the whole query, this is an R thing and those are not seen by the DBMS.